# How to get all consecutive sequences of numbers from given set of numbers?

Tags: python, sequence

I will start the description of the problem with an example so that the question is clear.

List of numbers: **[1,2,3,4]**

How can I get each successive string: **[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2],[2,3],[2,3,4],[3],[3,4],[4]]**

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while and managed to get **[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]** with lots of useless repetitions.

```
list = [1,2,3,4]

i = 0
j = 0
tempList = []
sequancesList = []

while i < len(list):
    while j < len(list):
        tempList.append(list[j])
        sequancesList.append(tempList)
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = i
    tempList = []

def deleteDuplicates(list):
    noduplist = []
    for element in list:
        if element not in noduplist:
            noduplist.append(element)
    return noduplist

finalSequancesList = deleteDuplicates(sequancesList)

print(finalSequancesList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]

sequancesList = []

for i in range(len(list)):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(i,len(list)):
        tmp.append(list[j])
        sequancesList.append(tmp[:])

print(sequancesList)
```

-> `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]`

Comment: Generally works, but fails if the list does not start with 1 since `len(list)` is used instead of `max(list)`. I would also avoid calling a variable `list` since this overwrites the `list()`-function

Comment: By using the index, we're ignoring the numerical values and the ascending order of the list, thus the numbers on the list itself does not matter. I named the variable as `list` according to the code presented.

Comment: True, overlooked the fact that you used the index instead of the actual number. Maybe you could still point this out in your answer simply as a way to ensure code cleanness for Sosek

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As was stated in the comments, the approach below works only if the list contains whole, ascending numbers and not in other instances.

There are two ways to do this, either as a nested for-loop or a one-liner using list-comprehension. Both versions below:

Nested for-loop

```
nrs = list(range(1,5))
result = []
for i in nrs:
    for j in range(i, max(nrs)+1):
        result.append(list(range(i,j+1)))
print(result)
```

List-comprehension

```
result = [list(range(i,j+1)) for i in nrs for j in range(i, max(nrs)+1)]
print(result)
```

Comment: What if it's a list of characters? Or numbers of different ranges?

Comment: That would depend on what you are trying to achieve. For me to give a sensible answer, you would have to specify what your exact requirements are. Characters, you could simply replace integers by their corresponding characters in the results if you are trying to replicate this with an alphabet. For different ranges: Do you want to include all intermediary numbers? What is your step-width? Should only those appear that are in the original list? ...

Comment: I'm not the OP if it wasn't clear, I just pointed up a problem with your approach.. (I didn't downvote your answer though)

Comment: This only works for consecutive ascending whole numbers though.

Comment: True both of you. OP picked whole numbers and I didn't question whether other options were required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generator that does exactly that:

```
def iter_successive(input_list):
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(input_list)+1):
            yield input_list[i:j]

>>> list(iter_successive(input_list))
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

---

Comparable one-liner solution:

```
def iter_successive(input_list):
    return (input_list[i:j] for i in range(len(input_list))
            for j in range(i+1,len(input_list)+1))
```